# C#, EmguCV - Color and circle detection in image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, image-segmentation

I try to detect and count circles in image (for example smarties)

I use HSL color space. But I am not able to distiguish colors od the same color if they are in touch. I try to erode and dilate picture. But result is the same, I have only some blobs(connected components) od the same color. Do you have some general algorithm for this problem?

(I try to do that with EMGUCV library)
I cant send image, because I have small reputation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how much the circles overlap? because they loose their circularity in some cases

Comment: The circles only touch, or they are very close together.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a similar problem asked [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10262/jigsaw-puzzle-isolating-the-pieces-separating-stuck-blobs). This is the case when 2 circles form a single blob. This has already been addressed with the watershed of the distance function of the blob [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304387/image-segmentation-of-a-blob-that-is-two-objects). There is a better demonstration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294859/how-to-define-the-markers-for-watershed-in-opencv) with example showing how to separate a bunch of circular pills of same color that need separation.